# Destructor called twice

Tags: c++, vector

EDIT: Turns out that this happens whether or not I use a vector. It has to do with objects local to the function having automatic destruction, despite my attempted explicit call to the destructor.

I'm trying to figure out why my object is apparently deleted twice. I was experimenting with the std::vector class and wanted to see how deletion of  a object was handled. Can anyone enlighten me as to what is going on in this situation?

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include"DummyClass.h"
using namespace std;

void main(void){
    //Make vector
    vector<DummyClass> objVect1;

    //Make objects to contain
    DummyClass test;

    //pass by value
    objVect1.push_back(test);   //makes a pass-by-value copy, I think?


    //Delete the objects stored in the array 
    objVect1.clear();   // call dtor (vector's copy)

    test.~DummyClass(); //call dtor on test
}                       //dtor called on test again?
```

console output:

```
0033F9DB was constructed
0062C200 was destructed
0033F9DB was destructed
0033F9DB was destructed
```

The last object is destructed two times. I am trying to figure out what is going on. It seems there was no constructor called for the copy-by-value argument passed into the vector. Can anyone help me figure this out? Thanks!

The class header is:

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
class DummyClass
{
public:
    DummyClass();
    ~DummyClass();
};
```

The class cpp is:

```
DummyClass::DummyClass()
{    
    std::cout << this << " was constructed" << std::endl;
}

DummyClass::~DummyClass()
{
    std::cout << this << " was destructed"<< std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the vector has anything to do with this? Did you try removing it? (Rhetorical question.)

Comment: Actually, I just removed it and you're right, the vector isn't part of the problem.

Comment: `void main` yields **undefined behavior** because it's invalid. After that you have no guarantees.

Comment: @juanchopanza I guess my explicit call to the destructor doesn't truly deconstruct the object?

Comment: It's called a *destructor* not a *deconstructor*

Comment: destructors are only called explicitly when you use `new` followed by a `delete`.

Comment: @rrauenza A destructor should be called explicitly when using [placement new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new).

Comment: @JamesAdkison That's what I meant:  *are only called explicitly [by programmers]*

Comment: @MattStone: Yes, your explicit call to the destuctor does destroy the object. The second call, which is generated by the compiler, is undefined behavior. But since you can't stop the implicit one from happening, it's best not to call it explicitly yourself.

Comment: The argument to push_back() is not pass by value. Rather it's pass by ref. But somehow this call creates a copy internally which is showing up destructed.

Comment: Why are you calling the destructor yourself???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The last object is deconstructed two times.

Once when you explicitly destruct it, and then once again when the function ends and all variables local to the function auto-destruct. This is undefined behavior.

You should almost never call a destructor yourself.

Answer (score 3):

```
DummyClass test;
```

This object is in the `main` function and will go out of scope when `main` returns. (1 destructor called)

```
objVect1.push_back(test);
```

A copy of the `DummyClass` is added to the `std::vector`.

```
objVect1.clear();
```

The copy is destroyed when `clear` is called. (1 destructor called)

```
test.~DummyClass()
```

You should not be explicitly calling this destructor, it happens automatically when the object goes out of scope (i.e., when the `main` function returns). (1 destructor called)

The destructor function was called `3` times, as shown above, for `2` object instances. The explicit destructor call should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call the destructor at the end of your main. It is automatically called once "test" goes out of scope. Remove the last line of your main.

Answer (score 0):

push_back() copies `test` into the vector. The destructor is called for the first time when the vector gets `clear`()ed, and the copy in the vector gets destroyed.

The destructor gets called the second time when you explicitly invoke it.

And the third time when `main()` returns, and `test` gets really destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment but I think that the first call is made after `clear` and the `test` object is destoyed; the second one is called by your call.